# Best way to get everything after a matching string, including the matching string?

Tags: bash

I have an xml file and I want to use grep (or use an alternative command) to get everything after `<id>thisIsATest</id>`, **including** the matching string I just specified.

Whats the best way to go about doing this? I have seen multiple queries to get **after** a matching string, but excludes the string being searched from the final output.

So the output would be:

```
<id>thisIsATest</id>
... rest of xml file after the above tag
```

Comment: you should post the input xml and expected output

Comment: Hi Roman, I have added the expected output.

Comment: hi, it's unclear: should it operate with **tags** or with **text**? Should the closing "root" tag be in the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse xml with regular expressions. For quick, *unstable*, **dirty** hack on the command line you may use `awk`:

```
awk '/<id>thisIsATest<\/id>/{p=1}p' input.file
```

Explanation, I'm checking for the pattern `<id>thisIsATest<\/id>` and setting the variable `p=1` once it is found. If `p` is true, `awk` will print the lines, meaning any line from the occurrence of pattern, including it.